# How can I get the first character of a string?

Tags: c#

for example, i have some string

```
var a = '2,,2,';
var b = ',,,'
```

how to get only first character,

so i will get

```
a = '2'
b = ','
```

Comment: `a[0]` or `b[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the index of the character you want, so:
    a[0]

For a complete answer:

```
char getFirstChar(string inString, char defaultChar)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inString)) return defaultChar;
    return inString[0];
}
```

Comment: why the default char?

Answer (score 2):

```
 string a= "abc";
 string subString = a.Substring(0,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "abcdefg";
string sB = s[0];
```

sB = "a"

Answer (score 0):

Characters in Strings can be accessed in the same way as arrays.

So for example, to get the first character in a string variable `name` you use the expression `name[0]`